# Find And Replace with Conversion

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to convert all the text "0.236" in the find object but not all the instances it finds are changing.

Some help to fix this macro would be great.

Thank you.

```
Sub ConvertTO6MM()

    Dim wrdFind As Find
    Dim wrdRng As Range
    Dim wrdDoc As Document

    Set wrdDoc = Application.ActiveDocument
    Set wrdRng = wrdDoc.Content
    Set wrdFind = wrdRng.Find

    With wrdFind

        .Forward = True
        .MatchPhrase = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute FindText:="0.236"
                                                     
    End With
                                                                                                              
    Do While wrdFind.Execute = True

        wrdRng.Text = Round(0.236 * 25.4, 0) & " MM"

    Loop
                                                                                                                         
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for the loop as you can do this with replace. Just change the first `.Execute` to `.Execute FindText:="0.236", ReplaceWith:="6 MM", Replace:=wdReplaceAll`

Comment: To convert more than one value, you could study [Convert and format imperial distance (feet and inches) with high precision](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31931/Convert-and-format-imperial-distance-feet-and-inches-with-high-precision.html?preview=TbXtlf8IKMA%3D). Also note, that `M` can only stand for `Mega`; `meter` is `m`, and `milli` is `m`, thus `millimeter` is `mm`, not MM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Replacement object which represents the replace criteria for a find and replace operation. The properties and methods of the Replacement object correspond to the options in the `Find and Replace` dialog box (`Edit` menu).

The `Replacement` object is available from the `Find` object. The following example replaces all occurrences of the string "0.236" with "6 MM". The selection changes when the find criteria is found because the `Find` object is accessed from the `Selection` object.

```
With Selection.Find 
 '.ClearFormatting 
 .Text = "0.236" 
 '.Replacement.ClearFormatting 
 .Replacement.Text = "6 MM" 
 .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue 
End With
```